# RegEx for name validation in c#

Tags: c#, regex

Request your some help in constructing the RegEx that should follow

- Should start and end with alphanumeric char
- Should be minimum of 1 char
- Should not start/end with given special chars (-_',.)
- Shall contain (-_',.) in between the word

I have been using below RegExp

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9.,'\-_ ]*[a-zA-Z0-9]$
```

And it seems to be working fine except it requires minimum of 2 chars but my requirement is that name can be of 1 char too and in that case it should not be any of the given special chars (-_',.)

Any help in this will be much appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Use negative lookahead assertion: `^[a-zA-Z0-9](?!.*[-_',.]$)[\w.,' -]*$`

Comment: Logically, the minimum possible length to meet both rules 1 & 4 is 3 characters, since the special characters in rule 4 are not alphanumeric. There's no way to have a one character string that starts and ends with an alphanumeric character, but also contains a special (non-alphanumeric) in the middle. Should the world `shall` instead be `may`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap the 2nd and 3rd character class in an optional non capture group

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9.,'_ -]*[a-zA-Z0-9])?$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Cns6YF/1)

Comment: Thank you for your response and it seems to be working fine, I am doing testing and will update here if anything.

Answer (score 0):

This will match all criteria:

```
^\w{1,2}$|^\w+(['\-_]+\w*)+\w+$
```

First we handle the edge cases of 1-char and 2-char strings, that can only contain alphanumerical characters (`\w`).

The second part matches all strings starting with an alphanumerical character, that contain at least one special character and that end with a alphanumerical character. The `(['\-_]+\w*)` block matches multiple not necessarily consecutive special characters in the string (e.g. `a-a-a-a-a-a---aa`)